# Matching pivot and dataframe by nearest date

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes. One is a Pivot table containing three columns, an identifier, a date and a value. It looks like this:

[image]

The identifier is the CUSIP code.

My other dataframe contains over 50 columns but shares the identifier with the first dataframe.

It looks like this:

[image]

The CUSIP code is present in this dataframe as the common identifier.

There are multiple entries for each identifier, and they all have different starting and end dates.

What I would like to do is merge my 3-column dataframe with my large dateframe by matching the identifier (CUSIP) and using the closest match of the datetime column between the two.

I tried using the merge_asof tool, but that is only possible if the dates are sorted (which is not possible given that I have multiple entries for each date - several identifiers have values on each date).

Any ideas how to handle this?

Comment: could you provide a sample of both data frames?

Comment: It is not very easy as they are both in huge files that I import.

Comment: just share a sample of first 10,15 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my small dataframe was always reporting primo month values and the large dataframe ultimo month values, the easiest for me was to just change the ultimo dates to primo dates (of the next month).

To do this I used:

df['DATE'] = df['DATE'] + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)

Which returns 01-01-1990 if the value is 12-31-1989. From there I could merge the dataframes normally.